# What are Ansible module attributes?

Tags: ansible, documentation, ansible-module

Each Ansible module's documentation page has an *"Attributes"* section.

For example, [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#attributes) is the one for the `command` module. It has these attributes: `check_mode`, `diff_mode`, `platform` and `raw`.

In general, how do I use a module's attributes?

And in this particular example, what is the `platform` attribute and how do I use it?

Comment: It's documentation. You read it. In this case, the `platform` attribute says `Platform: posix`, so you look at it and it tells you that this module can run on POSIX systems.

Comment: Putting aside the snarky comment, that doesn't really help. I know for example that `check_mode` and `diff_mode` correspond to CLI switches. So I assume that I can "use" the `platform` attribute as well, somehow - maybe on the CLI or in a play. But I don't know how. I'd like to know whether I can use that attribute to run a task that only targets certain OSs.

Comment: No. Attributes are documentation. The only thing you can do with them is read them.

Comment: Here's the original proposal for new structured documentation fields, which ended up being implemented as attributes: https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/68

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What are Ansible module attributes?*

These are documentation only. They describe some of the capabilities and properties of the module.

> *I know for example that `check_mode` and `diff_mode` correspond to CLI switches.*

They mean only that the module which was developed has implemented the capabilities to use `check_mode` or `diff_mode`. In other words, they state only if `check_mode` or `diff_mode` "are supported" by the module and if you can take advantage of [Using check mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode) or [Using diff mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-diff-mode).

> *So I assume that I can "use" the `platform` attribute as well,*

No, as it states only for which target platform the module was developed. An attribure `platform: posix` means you can't use the module on Windows.

Some background information can be found within the [Developer Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/) of the Ansible documentation.

- [Ansible module architecture](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html)
- [Developing modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html)

---

> *I'd like to know whether I can ... run a task that only targets certain OSs.*

For such Use Case it is recommended to use [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) and [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts), specifically `os_family`.

**Some References**

for Windows targets ...

- [Ansible Issue #50601 - "*`ansible_os_family` ... when Windows ...*"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50601)
- [Ansible Issue #57485 - "*`ansible_os_family` condition ...*"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/57485)